# Отсортировать элементы с чётным значением в массиве целых чисел(C++)

Tags: c++

Написал такой код, но он не работает. Что нужно исправить?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, big, m;
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    int* mas = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> mas[i];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (mas[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            big = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (mas[j] > mas[big] && mas[j] % 2 == 0) big = j;
            }
            m = mas[i];
            mas[i] = mas[big];
            mas[big] = m;
        }
    }
    cout << mas;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А какие дополнительные требования? Например, нечетные должны оставаться на своих местах или могут быть перемещены?

Comment: cout умеет выводить содержимое массива???

Comment: Сортировка по убыванию. Нечетные элементы должны остаться на своих местах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код работает, но когда вы выводите mas то получаете адрес где лежит ваш массив.

Answer (score 0):

Массив нужно было выводить через цикл.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).